# Why can't I return the generic type T from this function?

Tags: rust

I want to return the reference type, but the first `make_debug` function implementation does not compile. What is the difference between using `T` or `impl std::fmt::Debug` for the return type of this function signature?

```rs
fn test() -> impl std::fmt::Debug + 'static {
    let value = "v".to_string();
    make_debug(&value)
}

// This function not work
// fn make_debug<'a, T: std::fmt::Debug>(_: &'a T) -> T {
//     42u8
// }

// This one works well
fn make_debug<'a, T: std::fmt::Debug>(_: &'a T) -> impl std::fmt::Debug {
    42u8
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=11e7d75cbe97a476779634116c3db354)

Comment: There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66207126/rust-generics-return-concrete-type) an hour ago

Comment: It's because imagine `make_debug::<String>(123)`. Then `make_debug` would return `String` but you're attempting to return `u8`

Comment: Yes, thank you, I understand. @pretzelhammer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `-> impl std::fmt::Debug` means "Hey, I'm gonna return you something of a type that implements Debug, but i don't know what that type is".

while using `-> T`  means "Hey, I'm gonna return something of the T type, which happens to implement Debug"

So the difference is, in the first case you can return a different type than the input and it will work as long as it implements the Debug trait. While the second case you MUST return something of the same type as the Input.

Comment: I find this explanation confusing: with `-> impl Debug` the function *does* know what the concrete type is, it's the *caller* that doesn't know. Whereas with generics the situation is reversed: the caller knows what `T` is but the callee doesn't (before monomorphization).